# Log4j doesn't create log file

Tags: java, spring, maven, log4j

I have spring boot app. I want add log4j logging system to my project. I've created log4j.properties file in resources. When i run app file with logs is not created. Here is my logs in console:

```
 2018-06-26 18:52:33.525  INFO 4496 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-06-26 18:52:33.530  INFO 4496 --- [           main] com.edsson.expopromoter.api.Application  : Started Application in 7.332 seconds (JVM running for 8.14)
2018-06-26 18:52:33.530  INFO 4496 --- [           main] com.edsson.expopromoter.api.Application  : =================== APPLICATION STARTED ======================
```

Here is my configuration file:

```
log4j.rootLogger= INFO, file
log4j.rootLogger.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File= log.log

log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p    %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

As i see time format for logs are not configured. So i make conclusion that logging is not configured. 
Here is my project structure

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
I tried to mark resources folder as sources. No result.

I use Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Why log4j instead of logback? FWIW Spring supports Log4J2, unsure if you're using the correct library. That said, take a look at: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html for some additional assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was next. Spring boot uses build in logging "logback". So At first you need to make logback unactive. Then add dependencies for new Logging system.

I've added this to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Then my configuration file became readable with name it was.